# XSP4 from Mono 2.10 not working under Windows

Tags: asp.net, windows, asp.net-mvc-2, mono, xsp

I'm trying to run any application on XSP4 web server using new Mono 2.10 (downloaded from windows installer bundle). I have already tried to run simple ASP.NET MVC2 project and ASP.NET. Both were simple applications stubs. In all cases in browser under `localhost:XXXX` it seems that page is loading but nothing happens. With Mono 2.8 it works without any problems. Any suggestions how I can debug or solve this problem?

PS. My windows firewall is turned off so it shouldn't be problem.

Comment: hey, I'm having the same issue here, did you get to fix this?

Comment: Mono 4.0.2 and the same problem, did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The latest MonoDevelop Beta, 2.6b1, contains an updated XSP4 and Mono.WebServer.XSP (aliased as MonoDevelop.Xsp.dll in this distribution, and from my experience must be placed in the GAC for it to work) which fixes this issue on 2.10.

Answer (score -1):

A good place to ask questions regarding ASP.NET using Mono is [Mono ASP.NET list](http://lists.ximian.com/mailman/listinfo/mono-aspnet-list)

Comment: http://go-mono.com/forums/#nabble-td3331066. I would argue if its "very good place", especially when taking activity on the list into account.

Comment: @jethro: I saw your email in the list, unfortunately nobody answered. Try the general Mono list, it's much more populated